# How to get the changes on a branch in Git

Tags: git, branch

What is the best way to get a log of commits on a branch since the time it was branched from the current branch? My solution so far is:

```
git log $(git merge-base HEAD branch)..branch
```

The documentation for [git-diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) indicates that `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B`. On the other hand, the documentation for [git-rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) indicates that `r1...r2` is defined as `r1 r2 --not $(git merge-base --all r1 r2)`.

Why are these different? Note that `git diff HEAD...branch` gives me the diffs I want, but the corresponding git log command gives me more than what I want.

In pictures, suppose this:

```
         x---y---z---branch
        /
---a---b---c---d---e---HEAD
```

I would like to get a log containing commits x, y, z.

- `git diff HEAD...branch` gives these commits
- however, `git log HEAD...branch` gives x, y, z, c, d, e.

Comment: You're using "git log" incorrectly for your purposes from what I can see. I have added my answer below.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

In the context of a revision list, `A...B` is how `git-rev-parse` defines it. git-log takes a revision list. `git-diff` does not take a list of revisions - it takes one or two revisions, and has defined the `A...B` syntax to mean how it's defined in the `git-diff` manpage. If `git-diff` did not explicitly define `A...B`, then that syntax would be invalid. Note that the `git-rev-parse` manpage describes `A...B` in the "Specifying Ranges" section, and everything in that section is only valid in situations where a revision range is valid (i.e. when a revision list is desired).

To get a log containing just x, y, and z, try `git log HEAD..branch` (two dots, not three). This is identical to `git log branch --not HEAD`, and means all commits on branch that aren't on HEAD.

Comment: Wow, that's confusing. It turns out that using "git diff HEAD..branch" shows all commits (x, y, z, c, d, e), but "git log HEAD..branch" does exactly what I want and only shows x, y, z! This is the exact opposite of using "...".

Comment: `git diff HEAD..branch` is identical to `git diff HEAD branch`. The key thing to remember here is that log takes a list/range of revisions, while diff doesn't. That's why they treat their args differently.

Comment: Seems that `git diff HEAD...branch` (three dots) corresponds to the output of `git log HEAD..branch`

Comment: **HOT TIP:** If you want to see all the differences in the current branch since it was created use `git difftool --dir-diff main` (or master). All changes made will be displayed in the defined visual diff and merge tool. 

Answer (score 74):

```
git cherry branch [newbranch]
```

does exactly what you are asking, when you are in the `master` branch.

I am also very fond of:

```
git diff --name-status branch [newbranch]
```

Which isn't exactly what you're asking, but is still very useful in the same context.

Comment: 'git cherry' outputs a list of commit IDs. Can I convert these into a single diff combining all the changes in every commit?

Comment: @JonathanHartley Take the **first** and the **last** like of the commit IDs and thrown them to the `gif-diff`: `git diff x..z`, or for my own example it is `git diff 13bc4d..8eda3a`.

Comment: Its hard to understand which code must be replaced in your command as in which one of branch or newbranch is a keyword and which should be replaced with custom branch name

Answer (score 39):

What you want to see is the list of outgoing commits. You can do this using

```
git log master..branchName
```

or

```
git log master..branchName --oneline
```

Where I assume that "branchName" was created as a tracking branch of "master".

Similarly, to see the incoming changes you can use:

```
git log branchName..master
```

Comment: @A-B-B, if branchName is omitted, it defaults to "head", which is effectively branchName in the example above.

Answer (score 27):

When already in the branch in question use

```
git diff master...
```

Which combines several features:

- it's super short
- shows the actual changes
- Allow for master having moved forward

Comment: Or to specify branches explicitly: `git diff <branch1>...<branch2>` will show the changes introduced by `branch2`.

Comment: These comments are now outdated from updated answer.

Answer (score 25):

This is similar to the answer I posted on: [Preview a Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176278/preview-a-git-push/2831135#2831135)

Drop these functions into your Bash profile:

- gbout - git branch outgoing
- gbin  - git branch incoming

You can use this like:

- If on master: gbin branch1  <-- this
  will show you what's in branch1 and
  not in master
- If on master: gbout
  branch1 <-- this will show you what's
  in master that's not in branch 1

This will work with any branch.

```
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}

function gbin {
    echo branch \($1\) has these commits and \($(parse_git_branch)\) does not
    git log ..$1 --no-merges --format='%h | Author:%an | Date:%ad | %s' --date=local
}

function gbout {
    echo branch \($(parse_git_branch)\) has these commits and \($1\) does not
    git log $1.. --no-merges --format='%h | Author:%an | Date:%ad | %s' --date=local
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Throw a -p in there to see some FILE CHANGES

```
git log -p master..branch
```

Make some aliases:

```
alias gbc="git branch --no-color | sed -e '/^[^\*]/d' -e 's/* \\(.*\\)/\1/'"

alias gbl='git log -p master..\`gbc\`'
```

See a branch's unique commits:

```
gbl
```

Answer (score 7):

To see the log of the current branch since branching off master:

`git log master...`

If you are currently on master, to see the log of a different branch since it branched off master:

`git log ...other-branch`

Answer (score 4):

```
git log --cherry-mark --oneline from_branch...to_branch
```

(3dots) but sometimes it shows '+' instead of '='

Comment: 3 dots shows the first commit on the branch twice while two does not.

Answer (score 2):

I found

```
git diff <branch_with_changes> <branch_to_compare_to>
```

more useful, since you don't only get the commit messages but the whole diff. If you are already on the branch you want to see the changes of and (for instance) want to see what has changed to the master, you can use:

```
git diff HEAD master
```

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "git diff A...B(man)" learned "git diff --merge-base A B(man), which is a longer short-hand to say the same thing.

Thus you can do this using `git diff --merge-base <branch> HEAD`. This should be equivalent to `git diff <branch>...HEAD` but without the confusion of having to use range-notation in a diff.