# How can I generate a git diff of what's changed since the last time I pulled?

Tags: git, diff, rake, pull

I'd like to script, preferably in rake, the following actions into a single command:

1. Get the version of my local git repository.
2. Git pull the latest code.
3. Git diff from the version I extracted in step #1 to what is now in my local repository.

In other words, I want to get the latest code form the central repository and immediately generate a diff of what's changed since the last time I pulled.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You could do this fairly simply with refspecs.

```
git pull origin
git diff @{1}..
```

That will give you a diff of the current branch as it existed before and after the pull. Note that if the pull doesn't actually update the current branch, the diff will give you the wrong results. Another option is to explicitly record the current version:

```
current=`git rev-parse HEAD`
git pull origin
git diff $current..
```

I personally use an alias that simply shows me a log, in reverse order (i.e. oldest to newest), sans merges, of all the commits since my last pull. I run this every time my pull updates the branch:

```
git config --global alias.lcrev 'log --reverse --no-merges --stat @{1}..
```

Comment: @leemes: Hmm? `git diff HEAD` will show you what's changed between HEAD and your current working copy. That's not what Teflon Ted was asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I was looking for a command to show my changes since the last time I pulled and landed here. `git diff HEAD` worked for what I needed (at least I guess that it was what I was looking for :D)

Comment: Could someone explain (or tell me where to read up on) what `@{1}..` exactly measn? Just throwing it into Google doesn't help.

Comment: @user1129682: It's the syntax for accessing the [reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html). Without a branch name, it means access the reflog for the current branch. A value of `@{1}` means the most recent reflog entry, e.g. whatever the current branch pointed to before it pointed to the current commit.

Comment: +1, this is the correct way. You should expand a bit on the `@{1}..` notation, maybe explicitly put the defaults there and then show the compact version, so it's less magical.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm not sure if that's because I'm working on Windows or because this option was deprecated. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10275624/773334) did.

Answer (score 12):

[Greg's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002/how-can-i-generate-a-git-diff-of-whats-changed-since-the-last-time-i-pulled#61004) way should work (not me, other Greg :P). Regarding your comment, origin is a configuration variable that is set by Git when you clone the central repository to your local machine. Essentially, a Git repository remembers where it came from. You can, however, set these variables manually if you need to using git-config.

```
git config remote.origin.url <url>
```

where url is the remote path to your central repository.

Here is an example batch file that should work (I haven't tested it).

```
@ECHO off

:: Retrieve the changes, but don't merge them.
git fetch

:: Look at the new changes
git diff ...origin

:: Ask if you want to merge the new changes into HEAD
set /p PULL=Do you wish to pull the changes? (Y/N)
IF /I %PULL%==Y git pull
```

Comment: Typically you would use `git remote set-url origin <url>` instead of `git config` to change the URL for a Git *remote*.  Is there a difference? I don't know, but it seems that `git remote` is a more appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: @ColinDBennett You're right, `git remote set-url` would be the more appropriate way of doing it. I used `git config` because `set-url` wasn't an option when I originally wrote this.

Answer (score 11):

This is very similar to a question I asked about [how to get changes on a branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569/how-to-get-the-changes-on-a-branch-in-git). Note that the behaviour of git diff vs. git log is inconsistently different when using two dots vs. three dots. But, for your application you can use:

```
git fetch
git diff ...origin
```

After that, a `git pull` will merge the changes into your HEAD.

Comment: I don't see origin defined as a special keyword for git-diff or git-rev-parse. Did you mean that I need to plug in the hash from step #1 as the value for origin? If so, how do I programmatically extract that value? I'd like to combine all these steps into a single command/script for convenience.

Comment: Another way to do this is to use the special FETCH_HEAD head, which reflects the result of the previous fetch. So: "git fetch && git diff ...FETCH_HEAD".

Comment: I think this is the more appropriate response: `git fetch` followed by a `git diff origin/branchname` is the best way to check the difference before pull.

Answer (score 4):

If you drop this into your bash profile you'll be able to run grin (git remote incoming) and grout (git remote outgoing) to see diffs of commits that are incoming and outgoing for origin master.

```
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
}
function gd2 { 
 echo branch \($1\) has these commits and \($2\) does not 
 git log $2..$1 --no-merges --format='%h | Author:%an | Date:%ad | %s' --date=local
}
function grin {
 git fetch origin master
 gd2 FETCH_HEAD $(parse_git_branch)
}
function grout {
 git fetch origin master
 gd2 $(parse_git_branch) FETCH_HEAD
}
```

Comment: What is gd2? Some kind of alias to git diff?

Comment: It's a bash function defined in the script above just after parse_git_branch