# Compare current git-version with a specific version in git-history in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, I can go to git history for a specific file.

How do I compare a specific version in the git history with current version. The only thing I find in right-click menu is compare to previous, which I rarely use.

(Basically same question as
[Can I compare a version from Git history to the current version (that isn't committed yet) in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69933271/can-i-compare-a-version-from-git-history-to-the-current-version-that-isnt-comm))

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diff changed files versus previous versions after a pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428270/how-to-diff-changed-files-versus-previous-versions-after-a-pull)

Comment: Don't use visual studio git integration. It's terrible. Just use a command line or one of the third party tool like source tree or git extensions

Comment: @Liam:Thanks for your replies and tips.  I was hoping for a simpler way(than suggested link), like some extension. Ill keep this question open for a while, and If not I guess Ill have to use a 3rd party tool.

Comment: how much more simpler do you want? It's like 12 characters....

Comment: I mean simpler to use. I would like similar functionality as "compare with previous", but for current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git history, Ctrl+Click the two commits to compare (the latest vs the one you want to compare changes since) and select 'Compare Commits'

[image]

this should then open a new window showing all changes between commits.

[image]

I'm using visual studio 2022 Version `17.8.0`

Comment: Yes. I was so happy when it came! Thanks for updating the post to help others

Answer (score 0):

[image: This] was what I was looking for. New feature in VS2022, at least in v 17.3.4.