# how to diff two different files in index and a specific commit?

Tags: git

I want to diff for instance `a1.txt` from my `index` with `a2.txt` from `head~4` but I couldn't find any command for it... I tried `git diff --cached head~4:a2.txt a1.txt` but it didn't work, so I wonder what command I should use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to diff changed files versus previous versions after a pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428270/how-to-diff-changed-files-versus-previous-versions-after-a-pull)

Comment: no, that question answer is equivalent of `git diff head~1` which is a total different story...

Comment: Reference [a blob in the index](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltngtltpathgtemegem0READMEememREADMEem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify both endpoints of the comparison explicitly. Do not expect Git to do what you mean when you specify one endpoint fully, but not the other.

This should work:

```
git diff head~4:a2.txt :a1.txt
```

The `:a1.txt` specifies to take the content registered in the index.

Comment: tnx man, I have two other question, how about comparing two files in working tree and comparing  two different files one in index and other in working tree?@j6t

Comment: Use `--no-index` to compare arbitrary files. Use `git diff :a1.txt a2.txt` to compare a file in the index to a worktree file. Swapping the arguments doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you're a hero man...@j6t