# How do I do git pull so that it will update the files in the working

Tags: git, pull

When I do git pull origin master, it does not seem to update the files in the folder of the git repository.

Comment: Does the pull produce any error messages? If it succeeds, does it show a diff or say you're already up to date?

Comment: can you follow up on your question man?

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions,

Try a `git pull -v origin master` to see if the verbose version produces any clue.

If you can clone your repo and get it in a state before any `git pull`:

- Check if the git pull you just [did introduced any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002/how-can-i-generate-a-git-diff-of-whats-changed-since-the-last-time-i-pulled/62303#62303):

```
    current=`git rev-parse HEAD`
    git pull origin
    git diff $current..
```

- try a `git fetch origin master`, which is [equivalent to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070496/having-a-hard-time-understanding-git-fetch/1071300#1071300) "`git fetch origin master:`", not to "`git fetch origin master:master`" (i.e.: it stores fetched value of '`master`' branch (of remote '`origin`') in `FETCH_HEAD`, and not in '`master`' branch or remote-tracking '`remotes/origin/master`' branch.
  That means you can try and detect if any changes are to be introduced by that fetch:

```
     git diff ...FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can haz gremlinz.

`git-pull` is supposed to fetch the remote changes and merge them into the current branch.

To verify that the changes have been merged, do `git log` to verify that the revisions that you are expecting are in your local branch.

From [`git-pull` doco](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html):

> Merge into the current branch the remote branch next:
>
> `$ git pull origin next`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't make any change to the remote (or who ever maintains it didn't update it).

Maybe you have more than one remote and you're confused about which one `pull` is supposed to fetch form.