# Git: Command to tell what changed on commits applied for Azure Website Custom Deploy Script

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

Is it possible to execute a git command AFTER doing a git pull that will tell me everything that just changed on the git pull that was executed prior?

I'm deploying something to an Azure Website using continuous deployment from a git source-control. Azure allows for custom [deployment scripts](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments).

The way it works is that azure executes:
 1. A git pull (Which may pull more than one commit).
 2. A recursive submodule update
 3. A custom deployment script.
 4. Any post-deploy scripts

I only have control of what is done from steps 3 onward.

My application has a number of steps that needs to be run to optimize the code before it is deployed. However, the application also has static XML files.

What I'd like to do is identify if anything in the code changed, and if so run the lengthy code optimization deploy routine. If only XML files changed, instead run a shorter routine that puts those into place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
git diff @{1}
```

Explained properly in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002/how-can-i-generate-a-git-diff-of-whats-changed-since-the-last-time-i-pulled).