# how to identify branches that need to get merged in git

Tags: git, merge, branch

I make a lot of bugfix and feature branches and in the end merge them all into a release candidate (rc). but when i test the rc I am not sure if i have merged in all the branches. How can I find out which branches are missing?

I tried gitk, but it seems it shows only the branches that are already merged in the branch that I am on. But I am interested in the branches that are not merged.

There is a nice display of all the branches at github ("network"), but it is always behind, so it is not as useful as it could be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `gitk --all` to see all branches. Also, if you're on Windows, I'd recommend [QGit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qgit/) instead of `gitk`. It has a better rendering algorithm of the commits graph.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [git cherry](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html) (not to be confused with git cherry-pick).

Answer (score 2):

```
git branch --no-merged
```

is a clean way of showing the list of branches which need to be merged to the current branch.

"[How to get the changes on a branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2831173/6309)" references a nice script to format the result of that command.