# git: programmatically know by how much the branch is ahead/behind a remote branch

Tags: git, git-status

I would like to extract the information that is printed after a `git status`, which looks like:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
```

Of course I can parse the output of `git status` but this is not recommended since this human readable output is liable to change.

There are two problems:

1. How to know the remote tracked branch? It is often `origin/branch` but need not be.
2. How to get the numbers? How to know whether it is ahead/behind? By how many commits? And what about the diverged branch case?

Comment: How about this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773939/show-git-ahead-and-behind-info-for-all-branches-including-remotes

Comment: For Git 1.9/2.0, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20499690/6309

Comment: With Git 2.5+, the actual command would be: `git for-each-ref --format="%(push:track)" refs/heads`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30720387/6309).

Comment: If you don't necessarily want to compare against the tracking branch, but any two branches, I believe this answer is the best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433867/git-ahead-behind-info-between-master-and-branch/27940027#27940027 (works with git 1.9)

Comment: As for the point 2 of your question: `How to get the numbers? How to know whether it is ahead/behind? By how many commits? And what about the diverged branch case?` This answer worked wonderfully for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27940027/4209853

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**update**

As pointed out by amalloy, recent versions of git support finding the matching tracking branch for a given branch by giving "branchname@{upstream}" (or "branchname@{u}", or "@{u}" for the tracking branch of HEAD). This effectively supercedes the script below. You can do:

```sh
git rev-list @{u}..
git rev-list --left-right --boundary @{u}...
gitk @{u}...
```

etc. For example, I have `git q` aliased to `git log --pretty='...' @{u}..` to show me "queued" commits ready for pushing.

**original answer**

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to find the tracking branch in general, without parsing lots more git config than is practical in a few shell commands. But for many cases this will go a long way:

```sh
# work out the current branch name
currentbranch=$(expr $(git symbolic-ref HEAD) : 'refs/heads/\(.*\)')
[ -n "$currentbranch" ] || die "You don't seem to be on a branch"
# look up this branch in the configuration
remote=$(git config branch.$currentbranch.remote)
remote_ref=$(git config branch.$currentbranch.merge)
# convert the remote ref into the tracking ref... this is a hack
remote_branch=$(expr $remote_ref : 'refs/heads/\(.*\)')
tracking_branch=refs/remotes/$remote/$remote_branch
# now $tracking_branch should be the local ref tracking HEAD
git rev-list $tracking_branch..HEAD
```

Another, more brute-force, approach:

```
git rev-list HEAD --not --remotes
```

jamessan's answer explains how to find the relative differences between $tracking_branch and HEAD using `git rev-list`. One fun thing you can do:

```
git rev-list --left-right $tracking_branch...HEAD
```

(note *three* dots between $tracking_branch and HEAD). This will show commits on both "arms" with a distinguishing mark at the front: "<" for commits on $tracking_branch, and ">" for commits on HEAD.

Comment: Ecxellent! The three dots with `--left-right` is definitely an improvement on jamessan's answer. For the remote, I suppose the only robust way to go is, as you suggest, to read the git config...

Comment: Doesn't work for me - see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8294373/179332).

Comment: Isn't `@{u}` the current SHA of the branch you're tracking? I think your entire script could be replaced with `git rev-list @{u}..HEAD` in halfway-recent versions of git (ie, not four years old).

Comment: @amalloy yes, that seems to be the case. I don't know when it was added, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 23):

`git rev-list origin..HEAD` will show the commits that are in your current branch, but not origin -- i.e., whether you're ahead of origin and by which commits.

`git rev-list HEAD..origin` will show the opposite.

If both commands show commits, then you have diverged branches.

Comment: Thanks, the `rev-list` seems to work as expected, but `branch -r` does not give remote tracked branch accurately. I do not have the `origin/HEAD` that you wrote, yet there is a remote tracked branch, and I can get the number of commits with `rev-list`.

Comment: Hmm, it does seem that `branch -r` doesn't do what I thought.  Updated.

Answer (score 11):

You can try `git branch -v -v`. With `-v` flag given twice, it outputs names of upstream branches. Sample output:

```
* devel  7a5ff2c [origin/devel: ahead 1] smaller file status overlay icons
  master 37ca389 [origin/master] initial project check-in.
```

I think this format is more stable than `git status` output.

Comment: `git status` has the `--porcelain` flag which provides stable output, but it doesn't show the ahead/behind information.

Comment: excellent! I had never noticed this double option with git branch... it's pretty unusual to have a command with a double option, isn't it? Thanks for the tip

Comment: This looks nice and simple. I will use this.

Comment: @OlivierVerdier: Nah, that's not totally unheard of you. You've just probably seen it as `-vv` instead of `-v -v`. You see it occasionally to provide different levels of verbose output without adding distinct flags for each level.

Comment: @jamessan - you can use `--porcelain --branch` to see the ahead/behind info (though you need a pretty recent version of git for that, it isn't in 1.7.9 (ubuntu 12.04) but is in 1.8.3).  `--short --branch` is pretty much the same for now, and is available in 1.7.9

Comment: @HamishDowner, me, personally, would prefer your suggestion as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

In modern versions of git, `@{u}` points to the upstream of the current branch, if one is set.

So to count how many commits you are behind the remote tracking branch:

```
git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u}
```

And to see how far you are ahead of the remote, just switch the order:

```
git rev-list --count @{u}..HEAD
```

For a more human-readable summary, you could ask for a log instead:

```
git log --pretty=oneline @{u}..HEAD
```

For my own purposes, I am working on a script that will replace `@{u}` with an appropriate guess, if no upstream is yet set.  Unfortunately there is at this time no `@{d}` to represent the downstream (where you would push to).

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**
My original answer was actually not very good because it relied on the user to have a remote called "origin". It also failed if the current branch was had a tracking branch besides origin-head. These flaws essentially made it useless. However, the answer by @araqnid is not the most efficient method and the way he arrives at `$tracking_branch` is less than strait forward. The most efficient (fastest) method I have found to get the same functionality is the following:

```
# get the tracking-branch name
tracking_branch=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' $(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD))
# creates global variables $1 and $2 based on left vs. right tracking
# inspired by @adam_spiers
set -- $(git rev-list --left-right --count $tracking_branch...HEAD)
behind=$1
ahead=$2
```

---

### original answer: (inferior, but given for clarity)

Perhaps the simplest method I could find (inspired by @insidepower)

```
# count the number of logs
behind=$(git log --oneline HEAD..origin | wc -l)
ahead=$( git log --oneline origin..HEAD | wc -l)
```

I had previously been using the method of @araqnid, but now I think I'll move some of my scripts to this method since it is much simpler. This should work on any unix system.

Comment: When was the `--count` option to `got rev-list` added? It doesn't seem to exist in `git` 1.7.1 that I'm using.

Comment: I'm not sure which version it was introduced in, but it has been there since I started using git over a year ago. This email on the mailing list "[PATCH rev-list --count: separate count for --cherry-mark](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-rev-list-count-separate-count-for-cherry-mark-td6304977.html)" (v1.7.5) shows that it was available as far back as Apr 2011.

Comment: Sigh. Sadly one of the downsides of using a *supported* Linux like RHEL6 in an enterprise environment is having to struggle on with woefully old versions of some relatively fast moving software like `git`. Having done a little research, it looks like *lots* of useful functionality was added to git between 1.7.1 and 1.7.6. Unfortunately I can't find a page for `git` which is equivalent to the [WhatsNew](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew) page for `hg`.

Comment: Just to add to the original answer, you can get the name of the origin using:  `remote="$(git config --get branch.${branch}.remote 2>/dev/null)"` then you can just use the version in the original answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

`git status` has a `--porcelain` option that is intended for parsing by scripts. It is based on the `--short` output - they are almost identical at the time of writing (see the "Porcelain Format" section of the [git status man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/git-status.1.html#contenttoc4) for details).  The main difference is that `--short` has colour output.

By default no branch information is shown, but if you add the `--branch` option you will get output like:

```
git status --short --branch
## master...origin/master [ahead 1]
?? untrackedfile.txt
...
```

If you are up to date (after a fetch), the branch line will just be:

```
## master
```

If you are ahead:

```
## master...origin/master [ahead 1]
```

If you are behind:

```
## master...origin/master [behind 58]
```

And for both:

```
## master...origin/master [ahead 1, behind 58]
```

Note that `git status --porcelain --branch` is only available in [1.7.10.3](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.3.txt) or later (though `git status --short --branch` has been available since [1.7.2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.2.txt) ).

Comment: `--short` does color, `--porcelain` does no color

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't this work:

```
#!/bin/sh
git diff origin/master..HEAD --quiet --exit-code
RETVAL=$?
if [ $RETVAL -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "You need to git push!"
else
    echo "No git push necessary!"
fi
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because I wanted to know by how much the repo is ahead/behind the remote. Anyway, this question has already a pretty good answer.

Comment: I think for ahead, `RETVAL` would be the number of commits it is ahead. I am not sure if it works on 'behind' (e.g. _requires_ pull).

Answer (score 1):

The top chunk of code in araqnid's  answer doesn't work for me, so maybe something in git has changed since it was written 18 months ago.  It works if I change:

```
tracking_branch=refs/remotes/$remote/$remote_branch
```

to

```
tracking_branch=$remote/$remote_branch
```

However there is still an issue when tracking a local branch, in which case you have to trim the remote part (which becomes '.'):

```
tracking_branch=${tracking_branch#./}
```

Then you can programmatically obtain the number of revisions behind and ahead as follows:

```
set -- `git rev-list --left-right --count $tracking_branch...HEAD`
behind="$1"
ahead="$2"
```

I've written scripts to do all that (and more - e.g. they can also attempt to spot remotes on the other side of a git-svn bridge), and published them in [my git-config repository on github](https://github.com/aspiers/git-config#readme).  For example, here's my [git-compare-upstream](https://github.com/aspiers/git-config/blob/master/bin/git-compare-upstream).  See [the README](https://github.com/aspiers/git-config#readme) for installation instructions and other handy related scripts.

Answer (score 1):

> How to know the remote tracked branch? It is often `origin/branch` but need not be.

Git 2.5+ introduces a new shortcut which references the branch you are pushing to. `@{push}`: that would be the remote tracking branch which is of interest here.

That means you have another option to see ahead/behind for all branches which are configured to push to a branch.

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(push:track)" refs/heads
```

See more at "[Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720302/6309)"

Comment: Popularizing the new features =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin I do indeed ;) [Git 2.5 is coming](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a6309%20%22Git%202.5%22)

Answer (score 1):

With recent versions of git you should use

```
git status --porcelain --branch
```

and check for ahead/behind:

```
## master...origin/master [behind 1]
```

> --porcelain[=version]
>
> Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of
> user configuration. See below for details.
>
> -b, --branch
>
> Show the branch and tracking info even in short-format.