# Change the branch that git status compares with

Tags: git, github

When I type `git status` I see 
`Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.`
What if I have more than one remote, and I want to compare with a remote call 'feature', I type git status it still compare with origin. Is there a way that when I type `git status` I see
`Your branch is up-to-date with 'feature/master'.`?
Also is it possible to do something like git status feature -> compare local master with feature/master, or git status feature1 feature2 -> compare local master with feature1/master and feature2/master?

If not possible, what is the best way to see how many commits ahead/behind with certain remotes or branches(even with two different local branches)? I don't want `git diff` because that gives me too many details

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to change its upstream.
Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch

Comment: I think this question will guide you to an answer : [Show git ahead and behind info for all branches, including remotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773939/show-git-ahead-and-behind-info-for-all-branches-including-remotes)

Comment: @fpietka I don't think my question is related to upstream. And the one you posted is a totally different problem.

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC, my original thought was to use an easy command to compare (behind/ahead) any branch (doesn't matter if they are local or remote, or maybe even branches of different remotes). Of course I can always use `git diff` to see more details but sometimes I just want an rough idea of how much difference between branches. `git status` does a really good job but it only compares local and it's upstream. The answer in the link is really close to what I want, but it looks rather complicated and it can't compare any two given branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely based on [Show git ahead and behind info for all branches, including remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773939/show-git-ahead-and-behind-info-for-all-branches-including-remotes), here is a shell script which should allow you to have a "ahead ... behind ..." message for any two commits :

```
file ./ahead.sh :
#!/bin/bash
left=$1
right=$2

leftahead=`git rev-list --count $right..$left`
rightahead=`git rev-list --count $left..$right`

echo "$left (ahead $leftahead) | (behind $rightahead) $right"
```

usage :

```
$ ./ahead.sh HEAD origin/master
HEAD (ahead 7) | (behind 0) origin/master
```

---

`git rev-list $left..$right` displays the sequnce of commits starting from (but not including) the common ancestor for `$left` and `$right` up to `$right`.

`git rev-list --count $left..$right` will simply count the number of commits in this sequence.

Using both `git rev-list --count $left..$right` and `git rev-list --count $right..$left`, you get the ahead/behind counts (what is "ahead" and "behind" depends on which commit serves as reference).

---

For a list of modified files (*à la* `git status`), you can use `git diff --name-status` :

```
#!/bin/bash
left=$1
right=$2

leftahead=`git rev-list --count $right..$left`
rightahead=`git rev-list --count $left..$right`

echo "$left (ahead $leftahead) | (behind $rightahead) $right"
git diff --name-status $right $left
```

**update**

If `git diff --name-status` produces too long an output, the pager will kick in, and hide the initial `ahead | behind` line. Here is a fix, using the `--no-pager` option :

```
#!/bin/bash

function displayStatus {
  left=$1
  right=$2

  leftahead=`git rev-list --count $right..$left`
  rightahead=`git rev-list --count $left..$right`

  echo "$left (ahead $leftahead) | (behind $rightahead) $right"
  git --no-pager diff --name-status $right $left
}

displayStatus $1 $2 | less
```

Comment: This is awesome! Could you please add some comments to explain what the script does? Thanks so much!