# How do I get the differences in the number of commits between one certain branch and all other ones in Git?

Tags: git

I am not sure what the right name for the following diagram is, but it can be found

- on Github:

[image]

- in TFS:
  [image]

So my question goes:

- Is there a standard command in Git that displays the differences in the number of commits between one certain branch and all other ones?

Answer (score 1):

This question looks a lot like yours : [Show git ahead and behind info for all branches including remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773939/show-git-ahead-and-behind-info-for-all-branches-including-remotes)

---

I don't know of any standard git command that does this straight away, one command which shows the number of commits between `a` and `b` is :

```
git rev-list --count a..b
```

I adapted the answer above in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25161678/86072) and came up with a script to get the counters for two branches :

```
file ./ahead.sh :
#!/bin/bash
left=$1
right=$2

leftahead=`git rev-list --count $right..$left`
rightahead=`git rev-list --count $left..$right`

echo "$left (ahead $leftahead) | (behind $rightahead) $right"
```

usage :

```
$ ./ahead.sh HEAD origin/master
HEAD (ahead 7) | (behind 0) origin/master
```

You can adapt it to iterate through all branch heads and compares HEAD to the named branch.

Answer (score 0):

Combined with wc command will give you the commit count.

> git log --oneline branch_a..branch_b | wc -l