# Git-Bash *Prompt itself* Slow

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I have been working to make my own git-bash prompt. However, when loading up my prompt (set in ~/.bashrc), and after every subsequent command, it takes just a bit more than a half of a second so my input sometimes isn't registered/"spill over" when typing mutliple commands quickly. Obligatory pardon the code; I just want it all down and there before I clean up stupid ways of doing things. This is part of the function that shows the prompt, promptFunc: (git branch and #commits ahead/behind, the code doesn't really matter, just if it is the reason why it takes a while to load; if you find a better way to show this with just the numbers and up/down arrows, let me know, I am a bash noob).

```
local branch=`git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | cut -d"/" -f 3-`
if [ $branch ]; then 
            status=`git status -sb`
            read ahead behind <<<${status//[^0-9]/ } 
            if [ ! -z "$ahead" ] && [ -z "$behind" ] && [[ $status == *"behind"* ]]; then
                behind="$ahead"
                ahead=""
            fi
            if [ ! -z "$ahead" ]; then ahead="↑$ahead"; fi
            if [ ! -z "$behind" ]; then behind="↓$behind"; fi
            git_branch="\[\033[1;36m\]git:(\[\033[0;35m\]$branch$ahead$behind\[\033[1;36m\])"
        fi
```

The function is called, and PS1 is set to `*stuff*"$git_branch"` to access the output of this excerpt; then, `export PROMPT_COMMAND="promptFunc"` . If my prompt is simply not reappearing because of the "complexity", excuse the noob mistake.
As a precaution, the same is used to show virtualenv and executed in `promptFunc`:

```
if [ ! -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
            VIRT_ENV_TXT=""
            if [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "" ]; then
                VIRT_ENV_TXT="`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`"
            elif [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
                VIRT_ENV_TXT="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``]"
            fi
        fi
        if [ "${VIRT_ENV_TXT}" != "" ]; then
            venv="\[\033[1;36m\]""virtualenv:(\[\033[0;35m\]"${VIRT_ENV_TXT}"\[\033[1;36m\]) "
        fi
```

Any advice on how to speed things up or do things easier would be appreciated; will add clarification if needed.

Explicit PS1 Declaration; `$ruby` is the rvm:

```
PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[33m\]\w\n\[\033[32m\]\u\[\033[38;5;253m\]@\[\033[1;34m\]9570'
PS1="$PS1$ruby$venv$git_branch\[\033[0m\]""\n""$ "
```

Comment: You mention `git-bash` : you are running on Windows, aren't you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several actions on the filesystem are notoriously slower on Windows than on linux.

Try timing `git status -sb` in `git-bash`, to confirm if it is indeed the pain point in your performances :

- run `time git status -sb`
- set `GIT_TRACE=1` or `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1` and run your command :

  ```
  $ GIT_TRACE=1 git status -sb
  #   or :
  $ export GIT_TRACE=1
  #   the next invocations of your prompt code will make git dump
  #   information on STDERR
  ```

---

`git status` triggers a refresh of the index to be able to show a status for each file.

If it is indeed the slow point, you can try to get the `ahead / behind` count using other means :

[Change the branch that git status compares with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155750/change-the-branch-that-git-status-compares-with/25161678#25161678)

```
# you have to add some check that current branch does have a remote,
# or simply send error messages to /dev/null
remote=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{u} 2> /dev/null`
if [ -z "$remote" ]; then
    # no remote linked to current branch
    return
fi
head=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

leftahead=`git rev-list --count @{u}..HEAD`
rightahead=`git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u}`

echo "$head (ahead $leftahead) | (behind $rightahead) $remote"
```

Comment: Well, shouldnt've timed this at 1am; I'll make sure to give that a try for git status and all git commands I use in the future, along with some other code segments (I didn't even know it existed). And yes, I am on Windows.