# In Git, list names of branches with unpushed commits

Tags: git, branch

Given a project with several local branches, each tracking some remote branch, is there a command that lists all branches that have unpushed commits? (That is, even if none of those branches are checked out.)

I don't want to see the commits themselves, nor do I want to see branches that are up-to-date, I just want to see which branches are ahead of their remotes.

I have tried `git log --branches --not --remotes --simplify-by-decoration --decorate --oneline`, but it doesn't seem to show what I need. Running it on my current repo gives no output, but running `git status` on my current branch shows `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branchname' by 2 commits.`

`git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(push:track)" refs/heads` and `git branch -v` both show branches that are up to date as well as ones that need pushing. However, they *do* both show my current branch as `[ahead 2]`.

Other commands I have found eg. `git log @{u}..`, `git cherry -v` list the commits themselves, not the branches.

**Side question:** why would the output from `git log --branches --not --remotes --simplify-by-decoration --decorate --oneline` not include branches that `git branch -v` shows as ahead? Isn't the former command just looking at which `refs/heads` do not correspond to a known remote; so wouldn't a branch listed as `[ahead 2]` meet this criteria?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show git ahead and behind info for all branches, including remotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773939/show-git-ahead-and-behind-info-for-all-branches-including-remotes)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Interesting, but the accepted answer is a Bash script (I use Linux/OSX/Windows), and the other answer gives nearly empty output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay, I've identified the problem and this is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: I felt that the effort needed to give you a high quality answer would far exceed doing a thorough search here on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hah, I've been searching all day for this, and I didn't think to use the terms "ahead" and "behind" (or "track" etc.)!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay, upon reflection, it's not a duplicate. I'm also completely puzzled as to *why* there'd be a difference between what `branch -v` tells me vs. `log --branches --not --remotes --simplify-by-decoration --decorate`.

Comment: Might it make a difference that the branch where my `log` command doesn't work as expected is only ahead due to merge commits?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The `--no-walk` option to `log` seems to do a better job of what I need than `--simplify-by-decoration`. My full command is:

`git log --branches --not --remotes --no-walk --decorate --oneline`

...which I've aliased to `unpushed`.

Comment: Interesting alias. Good alternative to my answer. +1

Comment: In constrast to @VonC's answer this does show branches with no corresponding remotes, so YMMV depending on your workflow. For mine, this is preferable `:)`

Comment: how can i sort this by date?

Comment: @AryehBeitz Date of last commit? Or date of first branch commit?

Comment: @detly sort by date of last commit. Basically, I want the branches with newest unpushed commits

Comment: Or, if you have multiple remotes: `git log --branches --not --remotes=origin --no-walk --decorate --oneline` to see what you haven't pushed to the `origin` remote.

Comment: @BenediktKöppel Ah that's a good idea, I do often work with multiple remotes.

Comment: For me this also shows branches which are behind the remote and can be fast-forwarded. Those branches do not have unpushed local changes.

Comment: This was not useful for me. It lists basically every branch, even though exactly 0 have unpushed commits.

Answer (score 14):

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(push:track)" refs/heads
```

That remain the most precise answer that you can easily parse/grep to get the desired output (like removing up-to-date branches)

You can do so in a bash script that you will call `git-xxx` (no extension), somewhere in your `$PATH` or `%PATH%`.
That script can then be called with `git xxx`, and will use git bash.
That is portable and will work across platforms (meaning even on Windows, where `<Git For Windows>/usr/bin` includes 200+ linux commands (`grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `xargs`, ...)

Comment: Note that this doesn't highlight branches that are not tracking a remote (and which therefore have all unpushed commits).

Comment: @Tamlyn I agree. In the context of this question however, I focused only on local branches which have set a remote tracking branch.

Answer (score 7):

although the answers above are very helpful and show alot of data but
for others coming here looking for a solution to find local branches which are **ahead** i.e. have not been pushed yet. can get the exact list by executing:

```
git branch -v | grep ahead
```

Comment: Not sure if this works reliably... I just tried it after a commit (no push) to an existing branch  and no `ahead` text appears in the `git branch -v` command. This is with Git version `git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`. 
It did, however, work with an older Git version, `git version 2.13.0.windows.1`

Comment: I should also mention the test that did work on the older Git version was for a branch that existed on the remote and had a local un-pushed commit. However, it does not work for branches that do not exist on the remote (but I'm not sure if OP was asking about that scenario or not).

Comment: I modified it to find all branches out of sync with this:
`git branch -v |grep 'ahead\|behind'`

Comment: This does not show branches with no upstream at all, which could be a significant gotcha... It also doesn't work if the terminal language is not English.

Answer (score 5):

You can also see what branches are not yet merged to master

```
git checkout master
```

and then

```
git branch --no-merged
```

Comment: You can seemingly do this without checking out the branch first: "With --merged, only branches merged into the named commit (i.e. the branches whose tip commits are reachable from the named commit) will be listed. With --no-merged only branches not merged into the named commit will be listed. If the <commit> argument is missing it defaults to HEAD (i.e. the tip of the current branch)." https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch