# Tweaking script to pull all remotes branches

Tags: git

I've started to use one script posted in this another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076361/3809375):

```
#!/bin/bash

main() {
  REMOTES="$@";
  if [ -z "$REMOTES" ]; then
    REMOTES=$(git remote);
  fi
  REMOTES=$(echo "$REMOTES" | xargs -n1 echo)
  CLB=$(git branch -l|awk '/^\*/{print $2}');
  echo "$REMOTES" | while read REMOTE; do
    git remote update $REMOTE
    git remote show $REMOTE -n \
    | awk '/merges with remote/{print $5" "$1}' \
    | while read line; do
      RB=$(echo "$line"|cut -f1 -d" ");
      ARB="refs/remotes/$REMOTE/$RB";
      LB=$(echo "$line"|cut -f2 -d" ");
      ALB="refs/heads/$LB";
      NBEHIND=$(( $(git rev-list --count $ALB..$ARB 2>/dev/null) +0));
      NAHEAD=$(( $(git rev-list --count $ARB..$ALB 2>/dev/null) +0));
      if [ "$NBEHIND" -gt 0 ]; then
        if [ "$NAHEAD" -gt 0 ]; then
          echo " branch $LB is $NBEHIND commit(s) behind and $NAHEAD commit(s) ahead of $REMOTE/$RB. could not be fast-forwarded";
        elif [ "$LB" = "$CLB" ]; then
          echo " branch $LB was $NBEHIND commit(s) behind of $REMOTE/$RB. fast-forward merge";
          git merge -q $ARB;
        else
          echo " branch $LB was $NBEHIND commit(s) behind of $REMOTE/$RB. reseting local branch to remote";
          git branch -l -f $LB -t $ARB >/dev/null;
        fi
      fi
    done
  done
}

main $@
```

It works great so far but I was wondering how to tweak it to pull all branches, for some reason it won't pull certain local branches.

**First example**: I got 4 local branches behind with master being the current one, after running this script few branches (4) that were behind respect to the remote were pulled but I can still see the master branch behind the remote like the below picture:

[image]

**Second example**: before running the script I got this, 2 local branches behind and the current one (release) is fine:

[image]

I run the script and I got this:

[image]

So, how could i tweak the script to pull "all" local branches?

Comment: I only see the `master` branch as being behind after the pull.  Are there any other branches which are also still behind?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've updated my question with 2 examples, hope that clarifies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition [to my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543749/6309), I would add that your script should only limit the merge or reset of a given branch to it upstream branch.
Hence my use of `%(upstream:track)`

Here is the script I just tested with:

- git version 2.11.0.windows.1
- SourceTree 1.9.10.0

That is:

```
#!/bin/bash

branches=$(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname) %(upstream) %(upstream:track)" refs/heads)

echo "${branches}"
branch_checkedout=$(cat .git/HEAD|cut -f2 -d" ")
echo branch checked out: "${branch_checkedout}"

while read -r branch_line; do
  ahead=0
  behind=0
  branch_local=$(echo ${branch_line}|cut -f1 -d" ")
  branch_remote=$(echo ${branch_line}|cut -f2 -d" ")
  echo ${branch_line} | grep "ahead" >/dev/null && ahead=1
  echo ${branch_line} | grep "behind" >/dev/null && behind=1
  NAHEAD=$(( $(git rev-list --count ${branch_remote}..${branch_local} 2>/dev/null) +0))
  NBEHIND=$(( $(git rev-list --count ${branch_local}..${branch_remote} 2>/dev/null) +0));

  if [ "$NBEHIND" -gt 0 ]; then
    if [ "$NAHEAD" -gt 0 ]; then
      echo " branch $LB is $NBEHIND commit(s) behind and $NAHEAD commit(s) ahead of $REMOTE/$RB. could not be fast-forwarded";
    elif [ "${branch_local}" = "${branch_checkedout}" ]; then
      echo " branch ${branch_local} was $NBEHIND commit(s) behind of ${branch_remote}. fast-forward merge";
      echo "git merge -q ${branch_remote}"
      git merge -q ${branch_remote};
    else
      echo " branch ${branch_local} was $NBEHIND commit(s) behind of ${branch_remote}. reseting local branch to remote";
      bl=${branch_local#*/}
      bl=${bl#*/}
      echo "git branch -l -f ${bl} -t ${branch_remote}"
      git branch -l -f ${bl} -t ${branch_remote} >/dev/null;
    fi
  fi
done <<< "${branches}"
```

Note the use of:

- `branches=$(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname) %(upstream) %(upstream:track)" refs/heads)`
  to get both the full upstream branch name, and the ahead/behind status
- `branch_checkedout=$(cat .git/HEAD|cut -f2 -d" ")` to get the name of the checked out branch
- `while read -r branch_line; do` to loop *only* on the branches with upstreams, and not "all the remotes" (which might or might not include a given branch)

Comment: Thank you very much, i've tested with `git version 2.10.1.windows.1` and `sourcetree 1.5.2` and it's worked so far very good. I hadn't had time to test it before. Btw, do you foresee any case where you need to be specially careful before using your script?

Comment: @BPL So far, I didn't get any special case. I'll check with repo involving submodule entries, to see if that is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

First check your [upstream branch for `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171550/6309): it might not be `origin`, which is why pulling from origin might not have any effect for `master`.

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
```

Second, to display in a script the number of commits ahead/behind, use the [Git 1.9 syntax `%(upstream:track)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20499690/6309) :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)" refs/heads
```

Note that the upstream branch (or remote tracking branch, that is the branch you are pulling from) might differs from the branch you are pushing to.
Check if you see a push url with:

```
git config --get-regexp branch.master
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Could you please specify how to integrate those 3 command in the script so I can test it out? I'm a total newbie with git so I'm kinda lost with those commands per-se

Comment: @BPL The command 1 and 3 are for you to check out how master is configured: what is its remote tracking branch (or "upstream" branch, ie from which remote branch it is pulling), and what is its push branch. The command 2 is to be used as is, with your script having to parse its output (as you are doing currently): so try command 2 in a repo and see how its output is, in order to parse it.

Comment: I haven't validated yet your answer cos I don't know how to tweak the script with them. In any case, let's say I got this [repo](http://www.screencast.com/t/KNWkHA6e), if i try your commands 1&3 individually I'll get [this](http://screencast.com/t/VOxK2HpsVhGk). If you were so kind to put the final script including your 3 command so I could test it out I'd could validate your answer, thanks for your time in any case.

Comment: @BPL What version of SourceTree are you using? Are you using the embedded Git or a Git installed on your computer? What is your version of Git used in this SourceTree?

Comment: Using System Git version 2.10.1 + SourceTree 1.5.2.0 combo. After trying SourceTree 1.6.x or latest SourceTree 1.9.x I must to say there is no real reason for me to upgrade further, didn't like some Attlasian decission with those later versions so I'm fine staying with this reasonable fast/(no many buggy) old version :)

Comment: @BPL OK, that explains why I did not reproduce right away the issue (I use the latest 1.9.6.1). I will try your script.

Comment: Hi, did you finally try this one?

Comment: @BPL Sorry, I didn't get the chance to try it out.

Comment: Ok, giving you the bounties cos don't want them to be wasted... But I can't validate this yet.

Comment: @BPL Still, just for testing, it would be interesting to check with the latest SourceTree has the same issue.