# How to make certain, that your local working directory does not contain any changes?

Tags: git

Today I experienced, that

```
git status
```

is not sufficient to establish, that there are no changes in ones working directory, which aren't also stored in the (remote) repository.
So, how can this be established?

PS.

```
git status
```

said

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I switched to another branch using

```
git checkout branchName
```

which contained local commits -- I was not even aware that this is possible.

Comment: What does git status and git fetch origin say?

Comment: _"is not sufficient to establish, that there are no changes in ones working directory"_ - yes it is. _"which aren't also stored in the (remote) repository"_ - changes aren't stored in the remote, but commits are.

Comment: @evolutionxbox -- I've to use "git push" in order to get commits into the remote. So your statement is wrong.

Comment: I think you commented on the wrong question. `git fetch` is to _fetch_ commits from the remote, but `git status` still won't show the _changes_ only how many commits the local branch is "ahead" or "behind".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have misunderstood the response from `git status` and what it means to have a "local working directory" in `git`.

For basically every use case, each `git` command you run will only operate on the current *local branch*. If you have multiple local branches on your machine, usual `git` commands won't traverse them; your work is compartmentalized.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git status
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git checkout myBranch
$ git status
local 'myBranch' is ahead of 'remote/myBranch' by 3 commits
$ git checkout myOtherBranch
$ git status
local 'myOtherBranch' is behind 'remote/myOtherBranch' by 2 commits
```

You are changing contexts when you change branches (as you should be). There is `git` voodoo that you can invoke to see all branch statuses at once. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774433/2708650).

Comment: Please answer the question asked. I established by myself that my understanding is not correct!

Comment: The answer that I linked is short-and-sweet. It provides a script that can be copy-pasted into a file on your system. The second block in the answer shows an invocation of the script and the output you should expect.

Comment: The script linked iterates over the local branches and reports back how far ahead and/or behind the remote branch they are. The reason that I linked the answer is because the script already exists and you do not have to write it yourself. I do not think the snark in your comments was warranted.