# How to show `git status` for branches other than the current one?

Tags: git, branch, git-status

To get to know how far ahead and/or behind a branch is compared to its remote,  there's the `git status` command.

But `git status` only shows the status of the current branch.

Looks like to get to know the status of the other branches in the same directory, I need to switch to each branch and run `git status` again.

However, switching branches is not always possible, as the current branch may not be clean.

Is there any way to get to know the status of the other branches without switching to the other branches?

Comment: Have a look at using `git branch -vv` and see if that does what you want?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, that also contains the ahead/behind information. Thanx.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Excellent solution, maybe even `git branch -vv | grep branchname` to filter through the kludge. Should have been an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To directly answer the question that you posed in the title: you *can't* run `git status` in other branches.  `git status` shows you two key pieces of information: how you have changed the index (how you have staged changes) that are different from the most recent commit on your branch, and how you have changed the working directory and made changes that you haven't staged.

In other words, `status` shows you a combined diff of the HEAD to the index with a diff of the index to the working directory.  So it only makes sense to get the equivalent of `git status` on the current branch, since it takes the index and working directory into account.

With that caveat out of the way, it sounds like you're only interested in ahead/behind count, and you want the ahead/behind count for some other branch compared to its upstream.

Even though ahead/behind count is one of the things `git status` shows as somewhat ancillary information, it is the easiest way to find the ahead/behind count for the current branch, as you noted.

To show ahead/behind for *all* branches, you can use [the helpful script in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20499690/729881).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the below to temporarily set the remote tracking branch

```
git branch -u <remote>/<branch>
```

And then `git status` will display what you need.

Edit: You might want something like this instead (see the script in the first answer) [Show git ahead and behind info for all branches, including remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773939/show-git-ahead-and-behind-info-for-all-branches-including-remotes)

Comment: This sets the upstream, how does it solve the OPs question?

Comment: _"status of the other branches without switching"_ (from the question).

Comment: Sorry for the tone. You are correct, but it's not quite what the OP wanted.

Answer (score -3):

```
git status --branch yourLocalBranch
```

For detailed explanation:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status

Comment: The `--branch` option does not do that, it only shows the current branch and tracking info when using `--short`