# Is there an option in Git to show deviations of all branches?

Tags: git

I'm looking for something like an option to `git branch` that'd be showing the diversions of all the branches, e.g.:

```
git branch --diff-track
* branch1    and 'origin/branch1' have diverged, 3/1 different commits each.
  branch2    is up to date with 'origin/branch2'.
  branch3    is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  branch4    is 2 commits behind 'origin/branch4'.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "diversions"? Remember, a branch is only a temporary pointer and can point to any commit. Branches themselves do not have history

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show git ahead and behind info for all branches, including remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773939/show-git-ahead-and-behind-info-for-all-branches-including-remotes)

Comment: After performing some further testing I learned that what I was looking for is done using `git branch -vv`