# Check if local git repo is ahead/behind remote

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, github

I'm developing a git plug-in, and I need to know when a local repo is *changed* (can commit changes), *ahead* (can push to remote) or *behind* (can pull from remote) using the command line.

This is what I am doing so far:

- *Can commit?*

  If `git diff-index --name-only --ignore-submodules HEAD --` returns something,
  then yes, there are changes to commit.
- *Can push?*

  If `git status -sb` contains the word *ahead* in it's output, then yes, there
  are commits to push.
- *Can pull?*

  Nothing implemented yet.

The *can commit?* part seems to work properly. *Can push?* only works for the master branch, and this is a huge problem.

How can I safely check if, on every branch, a git repo has changes to commit, commits to push, or needs a `git pull`?

Comment: For the push part, you will have with Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) `git for-each-ref --format="%(push:track)" refs/heads`. See much more [in my answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30720302/6309).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end, I implemented this in my C++11 [git-ws plugin](https://github.com/SuperV1234/git-ws).

```
string currentBranch = run("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"); 
bool canCommit = run("git diff-index --name-only --ignore-submodules HEAD --").empty();
bool canPush = stoi(run("git rev-list HEAD...origin/" + currentBranch + " --ignore-submodules --count")[0]) > 0;
```

Seems to work so far. `canPull` still needs to be tested and implemented.

**Explanation:**

- `currentBranch` gets the console output, which is a string of the current branch name
- `canCommit` gets whether the console outputs something (difference between current changes and HEAD, ignoring submodules)
- `canPush` gets the count of changes between origin/`currentBranch` and the local repo - if `> 0`, the local repo can be pushed

Comment: Can push works for me with `git rev-list origin..HEAD`

Answer (score 30):

For future reference. As of Git v2.17.0

```
git status -sb
```

contains the word *behind* . 
So that can be used directly to check for pulls.

Note: Remember to run `git fetch` before running `git status -sb`

Answer (score 19):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20562900/4910876).

1. Do a fetch: `git fetch`.
2. Get how many commits current branch is behind: `behind_count = $(git rev-list --count HEAD..@{u})`.
3. Get how many commits current branch is ahead: `ahead_count = $(git rev-list --count @{u}..HEAD)`. (It assumes that where you fetch from is where you push to, see [`push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault) configuration option).
4. If both `behind_count` and `ahead_count` are 0, then current branch is up to date.
5. If `behind_count` is 0 and `ahead_count` is greater than 0, then current branch is ahead.
6. If `behind_count` is greater than 0 and `ahead_count` is 0, then current branch is behind.
7. If both `behind_count` and `ahead_count` are greater than 0, then current branch is diverged.

Explanation:

- [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) list all commits of giving commits range. `--count` option output how many commits would have been listed, and suppress all other output.
- `HEAD` names current branch.
- [`@{u}`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem) refers to the local upstream of current branch (configured with `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`). There is also [`@{push}`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtpushemegemmasterpushemempushem), it is usually points to the same as `@{u}`.
- [`<rev1>..<rev2>`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrev1gtltrev2gtem) specifies commits range that include commits that are reachable from  but exclude those that are reachable from . When either  or  is omitted, it defaults to HEAD.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with a combination of `git merge-base` and `git rev-parse`. If `git merge-base <branch> <remote branch>` returns the same as `git rev-parse <remote branch>`, then your local branch is ahead. If it returns the same as `git rev-parse <branch>`, then your local branch is behind. If `merge-base` returns a different answer than either `rev-parse`, then the branches have diverged and you'll need to do a merge.

It would be best to do a `git fetch` before checking the branches, though, otherwise your determination of whether or not you need to pull will be out of date. You'll also want to verify that each branch you check has a remote tracking branch. You can use `git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' refs/heads/<branch>` to do that. That command will return the remote tracking branch of `<branch>` or the empty string if it doesn't have one. Somewhere on SO there's a different version which will return an error if the branch doesn't haven't a remote tracking branch, which may be more useful for your purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Trebor I just threw together a simple fish function for the purpose:

```
#! /usr/bin/fish
#
# Echos (to stdout) whether your branch is up-to-date, behind, ahead or diverged from another branch.
# Don't forget to fetch before calling.
#
# @param branch
# @param otherbranch
#
# @echo string up-to-date/behind/ahead/diverged
#
# @example
#
#   # if master is ahead of origin/master you can find out like this:
#   #
#   if test ( branch-status master origin/master ) = ahead
#
#      echo "We should push"
#
#   end
#
function branch-status

    set -l a $argv[ 1 ]
    set -l b $argv[ 2 ]

    set -l base ( git merge-base $a $b )
    set -l aref ( git rev-parse  $a    )
    set -l bref ( git rev-parse  $b    )

         if [ $aref = $bref ]; echo up-to-date

    else if [ $aref = $base ]; echo behind
    else if [ $bref = $base ]; echo ahead

    else                     ; echo diverged
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  By far the clearest answer across several stack overflow articles.  I converted it into a bash script.

Answer (score 5):

I made a bash version of @user1115652 answer.

```
function branch_status() {
  local a="master" b="origin/master"
  local base=$( git merge-base $a $b )
  local aref=$( git rev-parse  $a )
  local bref=$( git rev-parse  $b )

  if [[ $aref == "$bref" ]]; then
    echo up-to-date
  elif [[ $aref == "$base" ]]; then
    echo behind
  elif [[ $bref == "$base" ]]; then
    echo ahead
  else
    echo diverged
  fi
}
```