# How to break on a *later* subtree modification in DevTools on github.com

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Webpages of forked GitHub repos display info such as "This branch is 10 commits behind". This used to be static HTML, but now that text appears with a delay. Specifically, a `<span>` is newly added with a `<span>` and sometimes `<a>` inside it.

I'm trying to find what code adds that info (and where that info comes from in that particular situation).

I use "Break on subtree modifications" in DevTools on parent/ancestor elements. After reloading the page, that breakpoint in some cases remains (maybe depending on which HTML element I add it to). But the breakpoint for some reason isn't triggered when the `<span>` gets added.

<s>Why isn't the "Break on subtree modifications" triggered, and</s> how can I find out what code adds the additional DOM elements?

**Edit**: I'm narrowing down the question, so that I can accept the current answer and ask the "why" part and about the origins of the info in separate questions.

Comment: You should be able to use a `MutationObserver` connected to the inspected element that display that information. Make a commit to test.

Comment: It means the site is replacing the ancestor element higher in the tree than the one you used.

Comment: @guest271314 There's no need to make a commit to a repo. The text appears later because it's not static HTML, because it's stupidly programmed, without need. This has nothing to do with when the commit was made. The commit is old.

Comment: @root If I understand the question correctly, a brief inspection of the relevant element reveals the parent is an element with the `data-testid="branch-info-bar"` attribute.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, that's the `<div>` whose contents change. Why doesn't the "Break on subtree modifications" get triggered?

Comment: @guest271314 *The info about the commit* appears *later*, *after* the page loads. That has *nothing to do with whether the commit is old*.

Comment: To be honest I have never used "Break on subtree modifications" in DevTools. In general, I use `MutationObserver`. Reading this https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints and following the instructions nothing is mentioned about the breakpoint surviving page reloads, which it doesn't on Chromium 124. The tedious approach would be to disable each page script one by one. Or try attaching the break point before any of the Web page scripts load.

Comment: @root I wonder why you need that info. What's your actual goal? If you want to get the info how far behind your fork is, you should be able to get that info via git commands.

Comment: Specifically, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/17719829/432681 for how to get the info of how far a branch is behind a remote branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM mutation breakpoints currently don't survive page reloads. That means, you have to set "Break on subtree modifications" on the ancestor element *before* it is modified. And in case of contents being loaded right after the page load, like in this case, you have to be quick.

In such cases, you can throttle the network speed to have more time to set the breakpoint. You can do that within the Network panel.

In the Chrome DevTools this option looks like this:
[image: Option to throttle the network speed within the Chrome DevTools]

And in the Firefox DevTools it looks like this:
[image: Option to throttle the network speed within the Firefox DevTools]

Reduce the network speed to some slow connection like "Slow 3G"/"Good 2G", then switch back to the Elements/Inspector panel, and set the option to break on subtree modifications on the ancestor element (the one with `[data-testid="branch-info-bar"]`) in this case.

Then the script execution will stop at the line where the element's contents are removed from the DOM.

For this case, this halts at a script remove-child-patch.ts (checked using the Firefox Debugger and source mapping to see the original sources):

[image: JavaScript execution stopped at a DOM breakpoint for subtree removal in Firefox (with source mapping enabled)]

As that's the code that removes the original contents but you want the one that adds the new ones, you have to ignore that line. In Firefox
you do that by right-clicking the line and choosing "Ignore line".

[image: Context menu for a line in the Debugger]

When you ignored that line, you can continue the script execution, which will then halt at the one that adds the new content (react-dom.production.min.js, with source mapping enabled):

[image: JavaScript execution stopped at a DOM breakpoint for subtree addition in Firefox (with source mapping enabled)]

Comment: [remove-child-patch.ts (link probably requires Referrer or query parameters)](https://github.githubassets.com/assets/ui/packages/remove-child-patch/remove-child-patch.ts) merely deletes two child `<div>`s, but it doesn't add the `<span>` with the text "This branch is 10 commits behind". The code that adds that doesn't trigger the breakpoints. That's the very weird thing that my question is about.

Comment: You're right. I missed that this was just the code that removes the element's contents. I've now updated the answer to show where the new contents are added and how to get there. Not sure, though, why you actually need that info. You should edit your question to clarify your intention.

Comment: Thank you! My first intention is described in the question: to understand why "Break on subtree modifications" isn't triggered by modifications. Specifically, why I have to choose "Ignore line" on *some* modifications in order for *other* modifications to trigger the breakpoint.

Comment: My second intention is to understand where the displayed info came from. In the call stack, the last `React` function `Hk` already has that info in `a.innerText`. But the previous function in the call stack, `J` from `scheduler.production.min.js`, doesn't have that info. How is that possible, am I misreading the call stack or something?

Comment: Another thing: It would be great if you could indicate the path to the source in future screenshots by not cropping the Sources pane.

Comment: My next intention is to fix [this bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68335748/5231110). It should remain a bookmarklet and it shouldn't use a rate-limited API.

Comment: I edited my question to narrow it down to only the first step of the aforementioned second intention, so that I can accept your answer and ask the other things in separate questions. Thanks!