# How can we tell which branch is newer in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have two branches: `origin/A` and `A` (locally).

Assuming one - and only one - has advanced by one commit, but I don't know which branch advanced, how do I tell which one has the extra commit?

Comment: If its always going to be 2 branches, the method specified by Makato would suffice. Else, I suggest you look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5972362/4433695

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: programmatically know by how much the branch is ahead/behind a remote branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969214/git-programmatically-know-by-how-much-the-branch-is-ahead-behind-a-remote-branc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git fetch` to get the latest commits from the tip of your remote, then use `git status` to tell whether or not your remote or local is ahead.

If `origin/A` is ahead, then when you run `git status`, you'll be told that your local `A` branch is *behind* origin by a commit.

If your local `A` is ahead, then when you run `git status`, you'll be told that your local `A` branch is *ahead of* origin by a commit.

Answer (score 1):

`git rev-list HEAD --count` will give you the number of commits on your current branch. Assuming you using github you can see the number of commits on the stop left of the repo.

Comment: This *kind of* works, but you've got to do the math yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to do this as part of an automated bash script, you can use the `git rev-parse` command. To see the commit hash of a given branch, use this command:

```
git rev-parse branchname
```

Or, to see the hash of the previous commit from a given branch, use this command:

```
git rev-parse branchname^
```

So, if you want to see which branch is ahead, you can run the following four commands and compare output:

```
git rev-parse A
git rev-parse origin/A^

git rev-parse A^
git rev-parse origin/A
```

If the output of the first and second commands match, then `A` is the branch with one additional commit. If the output of the third and fourth commands match, then `origin/A` is the branch with one additional commit.

If neither pair of commands has matching output, then you don't have one branch that is ahead of the other by exactly one commit.

Comment: I'm not sure that guarantees that there is only ever one commit discrepancy between the two branches.  It guarantees that there's a SHA difference, but not *necessarily* that there's a numeric difference between the number of commits on these branches.

Comment: You are right, this method only works if the assumption stated in the question are correct: *Assuming one - and only one - has advanced by one commit*. If that assumption is not correct, then *neither* of the command pairs I listed will compare correctly. However, if that assumption is correct, and the branches do differ by exactly one commit, then this method will work.

Comment: I'm not sure answering a terrible question with an answer very specific to the arbitrary nature of that question is a good thing.