# List Git commits not pushed to the origin yet

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits)

How do I list all commits which have not been pushed to the origin yet?

Alternatively, how to determine if a commit with particular hash have been pushed to the origin already?

Comment: Starting with Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015), the actual answer would be `git log @{push}..`. See that new shortcut `@{push}` (referencing the remote tracking branch you are pushing to) in [my answer at "Viewing Unpushed Git Commits"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30720302/6309)

Answer (score 488, accepted):

`git log origin/master..master`

or, more generally:

`git log <since>..<until>`

You can use this with grep to check for a specific, known commit:

`git log <since>..<until> | grep <commit-hash>`

Or you can also use git-rev-list to search for a specific commit:

`git rev-list origin/master | grep <commit-hash>`

Comment: What if you have already `git fetch`'d, and the origin contains more commits which you haven't pulled yet? then `origin/develop` is newer than `develop` - will this answer still give the expected list of commits not yet pushed to the origin?

Comment: @Kidburla Yes, this still works in that situation. `git log origin/develop..develop` will list any commits that haven't been pushed to the origin's develop branch. The reverse, `git log develop..origin/develop` will list any commits that are in origin's develop but haven't been pulled into the local develop yet.

Comment: If `<until>` is supposed to be the current HEAD (the last commit on the checked out branch), then it can simply be omitted. The two dots are still required though: `git log origin/master..` (same as `git log origin/master..HEAD`)

Comment: Very well explained with the general case (second snippet). I'd expect there be a command or shortcut for that operation as it's very useful and frequently needed. Is there a way to define a shorter version of getting the commits that aren't on the remote yet but to reside on the local branch?

Comment: "git log origin/master..HEAD" is what worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for adding the `git log <since>..<until>` explanation. Helped solidify my understanding.

Answer (score 41):

> how to determine if a commit with particular hash have been pushed to the origin already?

```
# list remote branches that contain $commit
git branch -r --contains $commit
```

Comment: try this : git cherry -v origin/master