# How can I check which commits have not been pushed to origin?

Tags: git

I have made commits to my local branch (let's just say master) and have 'git pull'd down changes that others have made. When I run a 'git status', I see something like:

```
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
```

How can I see a list of the four commits that I have made that have yet to be pushed to origin?

Comment: What about `git log origin/master..master`?

Comment: @Michal: Don't be shy about posting answers! (too late on this question, unfortunately)

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080509/git-list-commits-not-pushed-to-the-origin-yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Viewing unpushed Git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
git diff --stat origin/master
```

will show the changed files.

```
git log origin/master..master
```

will show the commits.

Comment: In recent versions of it, if you've set upstream information properly you can use something like `git log @{u}..`.

Comment: You can do the same with gitk, either using the "views" interface inside it, or just by launching it as `gitk origin/master..master`.

Comment: how do i check the different in files between origin and the file I have?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use gitk (or gitk --all) which will show this history of the branch.  It also displays large friendly labels on origin/master and master (and any other tags that you have).

A more lo tech version is git log --graph

Comment: 'git log --graph' is great but if there have been a lot of more recent commits from others, it is tough, if not impossible, to tell what are the commits I have yet to push.