# Commit differences between local and remote

Tags: git

How can I ask what commits are different between my current local branch and the remote repository that I push to?

Not exactly a `git diff origin/master master` -- I don't want to see code differences.  Just a list of changes like `git log`.

I want to quickly see how long it's been since I pushed and how out of sync I am.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Git can not send this information remotely.

You would have to do a Git fetch (fetching the changes, without altering your working copy). You will then have a branch called "origin/master" which will enable you to use `git log master..origin/master` to get the variance between the two.

```
git fetch
git log master..origin/master
```

Comment: In my case I had to reverse the order to `git log origin/master..master` as my local branch was ahead of remote, not behind. Upd.: oh, that's what [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057999/2750743) is about =D

Answer (score 42):

You can see which commits are on `origin/master` but not yet on `master` using

```
git log master..origin/master
```

To see which commits are on your `master` which you haven't yet pushed, use

```
git log origin/master..master
```

Comment: Probably should fetch first in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

`git log HEAD..origin/yourproject --graph`

Comment: A command as a solution is welcome, but please ensure you add context around it so your fellow users will understand it.

Answer (score -1):

With Visual Studio 2015 and Git version 2.7.1.windows.2, if you just type

```sh
git diff origin/master master --name-only
```

you will receive this:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

To work around that, run

```sh
git branch -a
```

which will return something like

```
* master

  remotes/yourproject
```

Then use the entire remote path as Git gives it to you, and it will work:

```sh
git diff remotes/yourproject master
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to _list the commits_ between the local and the remote heads, **not** how to show the code differences.