# How do I find out what commits have not been pushed or pulled yet?

Tags: git

I'm working in a branch that is remote tracking.
I've made several commits.

Is there any way to get a list of the commits I've made that I have NOT pushed yet?
Is there any way to get a list of the commits that I haven't pulled yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits - maybe this can help you. It's about not pushed.

Comment: Yup, seems to have been a duplicate, I was just unable to find the referenced question previously.
I ended up using the "git log ..@{u}" (and converse) syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a list of commits you have not yet pushed by running

```
git log origin/master..master
```

optionally swapping in some other branch name for `origin/master` and `master` (e.g., `origin/mybranch` and `mybranch`).

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
git diff master origin/master
```

might work.  But that will give you way more info than just the commit list, so you probably need to use different options.

Edit:  But you probably need to run

```
git fetch
```

first

Comment: `git log` should get you just a list of commits.

Comment: That's heading in the right direction, but the question was asking for the list of commits, not the diff.