# zsh - show if git branch have unpushed commits

Tags: git, ssh, terminal, zsh

Actually Im using a slightly modified version of the oh my zsh theme `blinks`. It show a SSH statement just for optical difference to my local terminal.
Also it show the branch and a little star if there are uncommitted changes in the branch.

Is it possible to show that there are unpushed commitments? Maybe also with a little indicator.

```
# https://github.com/blinks zsh theme

function _prompt_char() {
  if $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1); then
    echo "%{%F{blue}%}±%{%f%k%b%}"
  else
    echo ' '
  fi
}

case ${SOLARIZED_THEME:-dark} in
    light) bkg=white;;
    *)     bkg=black;;
esac

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX=" [%{%B%F{blue}%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{%f%k%b%K{${bkg}}%B%F{green}%}]"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY=" %{%F{red}%}*%{%f%k%b%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=""

PROMPT='%{%f%k%b%}

%{%K{black}%B%F{green}%}%n%{%B%F{blue}%}@%{%B%F{cyan}%}%m%{%B%F{green}%} %{%B%F{red}%}!!SSH!! %{%b%F{yellow}%K{black}%}%~%{%B%F{green}%}$(git_prompt_info)%E%{%f%k%b%}
%{%K{black}%}$(_prompt_char)%{%K{black}%} %#%{%f%k%b%} '

RPROMPT='!%{%B%F{cyan}%}%!%{%f%k%b%}'
```

thanks in advance
denym

Comment: Can you determine if you have unpushed commits without a network round-trip? In not then you don't want it in your prompt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`vcs_info`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information) module come with zsh.

There is a very detail tutorial shows you how to do it: http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/customize-zsh-prompt-with-vcs-info.html

Normally you only need to have `${vcs_info_msg_0_}` in your $PROMPT variable after you properly load the `vcs_info` module, but you can customized the prompt format if you don't like the default one.

BTW, `vcs_info`, as the name has suggested, also support other VCSs, e.g. svn, hg, cvs, etc.

Comment: So, how does one go about configuring `vcs_info` to display information about unpushed commits (i.e., commits that do not exist in the branch being tracked)? This answer is incomplete, at best.

Comment: @chepner If you have some time to read the article I linked in above answer, you might already know how to. fyi, copied from the article 

>    %u   Show unstaged changes in the repository
>    %c   Show staged changes in the repository
>
>    zstyle ':vcs_info:git*' formats "%s  %r/%S %b (%a) %m%u%c "

Comment: thanks for sharing this interesting article, it's hard to find stuff about this topic. However, staged changes (%c) and unstaged changes (%u) are not the same thing as unpushed commits

Answer (score 3):

Just set ZSH_THEME="mortalscumbag" in your ~/.zshrc... It supports the "unpushed" state...

```
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

(ssh) mdesales@pppdc9prd08i ‹ master ↑ › : ~/.oh-my-zsh
```

The "up arrow" shows that there are unpushed commits...

```
853102c dosdok
(END)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like explicit answers so I just looked into the theme provided by Marcello de Sales (depending on your install you should be able to find your themes in the `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/` directory).

Simply use the `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_AHEAD` global variable.

Here's an example showing a cyan arrow to the right:

```sh
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_AHEAD="%{$fg_no_bold[cyan]%}->"
```

Additionally, here's a [great post](https://blog.carbonfive.com/writing-zsh-themes-a-quickref/) which goes into a lot of detail explaining how to customize your zsh theme.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of doing this without running git commands by hand - since this feels a bit fragile. A maintained package would be great. I used to use `git_super_status`, but it seems to have stopped working. (2023)

Then [number5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29489/number5)'s 2013 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352147/6309) based on [`vcs_info`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information) remains the safest approach, if you want to avoid manual `git` commands and seek a maintained package.

First, enable the `vcs_info` module by adding the following lines to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git svn
precmd() {
    vcs_info
}
```

That code block will autoload the `vcs_info` module and make sure `vcs_info` is called before each command prompt display.

Then, develop a custom function to determine the ahead/behind status of your current branch relative to the upstream branch.
That can be done by inspecting the output of the `git rev-list` command, as seen in [this thread](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg00519.html) from 2021.

```
function +vi-git-st() {
    local ahead behind
    local -a gitstatus
    
    git rev-parse @{upstream} >/dev/null 2>&1 || return 0
    local -a x=( $(git rev-list --left-right --count HEAD...@{upstream} ) )
    
    (( $x[1] )) && gitstatus+=( "+${x[1]}" )  # ahead count
    (( $x[2] )) && gitstatus+=( "-${x[2]}" )  # behind count
    
    hook_com[misc]+=${(j:/:)gitstatus}
}
```

The `git rev-list --left-right --count HEAD...@{upstream}` command is used to get the ahead and behind commit counts.
The function then updates a custom [hook `hook_com[misc]`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Hooks-in-vcs_005finfo) with the ahead/behind information.

To utilize this custom function within `vcs_info`, add to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks git-st
```

That will tell `vcs_info` to call your custom `+vi-git-st` function when generating the VCS information for the prompt.

Finally, configure your ZSH prompt to display the VCS information by adding the following lines to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}%# '
```

It will substitute the VCS information into your prompt, displaying the ahead/behind commit count indicators when you are in a git repository.

Comment: Hmm, key vsc_info seems the way to go. I wonder if there is some repository with these functions.

Comment: P.S I would have given you the bounty - but I need to wait a day after the isuing the bounty.

Comment: @AttRigh As examples: [`zsh-users/zsh`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/457ab9f9fe12a093dd41a6c96bff6db209471ecc/Misc/vcs_info-examples#L207), [`jonathansick/dotfiles`](https://github.com/jonathansick/dotfiles/blob/0d433a960125474e11beb9d4a695029a1638078d/prompts/jsick_vcs_info.zsh#L39-L60), [`robobenklein/zinc`](https://github.com/robobenklein/zinc/blob/5436b2459a2a5d16533a07d977d6d097d59c25fb/zsdoc-src/zincs_vcs#L197-L212)

Answer (score 0):

Just test output from the commands in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016954/877115). That'll output your `HEAD` state against your local reference to `origin/master`, which is about as good as you can get without doing something against the remote, which as Douglas notes in his comment is an ill-fated idea.