# How can I diff between my repo and a remote repo that's not origin?

Tags: git, github

From [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits/2016954#2016954) I know how to make  diff between a repo on my own and my local commits:

```
git diff origin/master..HEAD
```

But, How can I do the same instead of origin using a `path/to/github/repo.git` ?

```
git diff https://github.com/malarres/universal.git/GPII-795..HEAD
```

is returning:

```
fatal: Invalid object name 'https'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I do the same instead of `origin` using a `path/to/github/repo.git` ?
>
> `git diff https://github.com/malarres/universal.git/GPII-795..HEAD`

That's not the way `git diff` works. If you want to diff between your local repo and another repo, you need to do the following:

1. Add the latter as a *remote* of the former. Note that nothing prevents you from defining multiple remotes, in addition to `origin`, within one repository. (You may want to choose a less generic remote name than "other", though.)

   ```
    git remote add other https://github.com/malarres/universal.git/GPII-795
   ```
2. Fetch everything from that remote:

   ```
    git fetch other
   ```
3. Run the appropriate `git diff` command, for instance,

   ```
    git diff other/master..HEAD
   ```

If you later want to remove that remote from your repository, you can run

```
git remote rm other
```