# Pull a commit from a different repository

Tags: git, commit, pull, git-fetch

I've cloned a project for me to work on, but a friend made a change on the original project. I would like to pull the changes from that commit into my project.

Using

```
git fetch https://github.com/cvandermeer/wisemonkeys.git f70bcfd75a498ed9159b6e5313e306166fc3df62
```

throws the following error:

> error: no such remote ref f70bcfd75a498ed9159b6e5313e306166fc3df62

`git remote -v` gives me the following,

```
origin  https://github.com/alucardu/appsynth.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/alucardu/appsynth.git (push)
```

Is it not possible to pull a commit from a different project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(For convenience, let's call your friend "Alice" in the following.)

### You fetch references (branches or tags), not commits

> I would like to pull the changes from that commit into my project.
>
> Is it not possible to pull a commit from a different project?

Strictly speaking, you don't fetch commits; you fetch *references* (branches or tags). If you're interested in a particular commit that exists in Alice's repo but not in yours, you'll need to fetch a reference whose ancestry contains the commit in question from Alice's repo.

### Use a valid `git fetch` syntax

> Using [...] throws the following error [...]

The command you're using,

```
git fetch <remote-url> <commit>
```

is not a valid `git fetch` syntax, hence the error you're getting. The syntax you want to use is

```
git fetch <repository>
```

where `<repository>` is a remote, i.e. a nickname under which your local repo knows Alice's repo. You may want to be more specific and also add a [refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) at the end of this command.

**Edit**: As pointed out by torek in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262554/pull-a-commit-from-a-different-repository/28263254#comment44889637_28263254), you can also use a naked URL, without configuring the remote in your local repository, but that's probably not what you want to do, here.

### Add Alice's repo as a *remote* first

> `git remote -v` gives me the following [...]

The output of `git remote -v` indicates that you haven't added Alice's repo as a *remote* of your local repository yet. You need to to that before you can fetch from it:

```
git remote add alice https://github.com/cvandermeer/wisemonkeys.git
```

### Fetch and find out more about the commit of interest

Then run

```
git fetch alice
```

to fetch everything you don't already have from Alice's repo. You can then run

```
git name-rev f70bcfd75a498ed9159b6e5313e306166fc3df62
```

to identify a reference from which the commit is accessible, and

```
git show f70bcfd75a498ed9159b6e5313e306166fc3df62
```

to print information about the commit and decide what to do with it (cherry-pick it, merge the branch it's on into one of your local branches, etc.).

### Additional resources

- [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) and [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) man pages
- related question: [How can I diff between my repo and a remote repo that's not origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979759/how-can-i-diff-between-my-repo-and-a-remote-repo-thats-not-origin/27979916#27979916)

Comment: For completeness, I'll add that you *can* supply a raw URL (and optional refspec(s)) to `git fetch` ... but you shouldn't unless you're very familiar with git and know what you are getting yourself into this way. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following sequence of actions:

1) Connect the other repository as a remote repository, with git remote.

2) Pull it.

3) Use `git cherry-pick` to pluck the commit from the other repository, into yours.