# Git: how to identify what changed?

Tags: git

I entered my office this morning, went to my local git repo and typed

```
git status

# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits. 
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

From this, I can see that I'm ahead of the origin branch. But is there a command I can use to find out **exactly which file(s)** or **which parts of the files** have differed?

Comment: Looks like this question has already been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits

Answer (score 1):

You list the differences to the `origin/master` branch by executing:

```
git diff origin/master
```

Comment: Don't you need to fetch the origin before: git fetch origin ?

Comment: Yes, but if you didn’t fetch the remote before, Git won’t be able to tell you that your branch is ahead of the remote branch.

Comment: @RenaudKern Yes and no. As `poke` mentioned: it would not be able to tell you that that your branch is ahead. On the other hand it might be that the master branch has new commits, therefore you are 2 commits ahead but X-commits behind.