# Git get the files which are not yet pushed to the repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I would like to get a list of files which are committed but not yet pushed. I tried `git diff --name-only` but this shows only the files which are changed but not yet committed. Once these file's are committed this commando does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits

Answer (score 0):

You want the diff between the branch and the remote branch:

```
git diff origin/my-branch my-branch --name-only
```

(assumes your remote is called `origin` in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers to [the question mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901), and [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) docs, the command should be:

```
$ git diff --name-only @{push}...HEAD
```

Note the 3 dots - it will make diff ignore upstream progress which happened since you created the branch or updated it last time.