# How to list all the files in commits that haven't been pushed?

Tags: git

I want to have a hook that will check for linting issues. The problem is that I don't want to check all the files in the project, I want to check only the files that have actually changed.

**Lets say I have 3 commits locally that I havent pushed to remote. How can I list (or even better, pipe them to another process)?**

Comment: What about `git diff --stat`?

Comment: use `git show <commit id>` it'll display files which got modified and committed with particular commit.

Comment: @BhanuSingh I want to use it in automatic process, theoretically I should not have to type the commit id.

Comment: Does this give you a start? [git-diff - Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits)

Comment: To see filenames involved in commits, use `git log --name-status`, so to see unpushed commits and the involved files you would use `git log --name-status origin/master..HEAD`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yep, thx. `git diff origin/master..HEAD --stat` is a start

Comment: With `git diff origin..HEAD --stat | awk '{print $1}' |` I can have a list of the files, now the burden is to pass this list to `eslint`

Comment: For completeness : `git diff --name-only` will list just the filenames.