# How to check what I'm going to commit?

Tags: git, github

I was working on some feature development using Git. In between I have got some urgent bug, so needed to switch on `develop branch` from `feature/2.8.0`. So to do that I run following commands (from shell history):

```
 2002  git status 
 2003  git stash 
 2004  git checkout develop 
 2005  git status 
 2006  git pull
 2007  git pull origin develop
```

Now here is my `git status`:

```
$ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   src/lib/eval/prvl_listed_securities_0000_hxx0401_init.erl
#   src/lib/eval/prvl_listed_securities_0000_hxx0401_proc.erl
#   src/view/eval/prvl_listed_securities_0000_hxx0401.html
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Here, I can see following lines :

```
>    # On branch develop
>    # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit.
>    #   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

From history, I haven't committed anything, How can I check what are my local commits needs to push?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`git show HEAD`
This shows the content of the commit from your current head

Comment: This is not the ideal command to use to get a list of unpushed commits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax to get a list of all local commits on branch `X` that haven't yet been pushed to the remote branch `origin/X`:

```
git log origin/X..X
```

The use is `..` is an example of a commit range. You can read more about how to use them from the [**FREE online Pro Git book**](http://git-scm.com/book), in particular the section on [commit ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges).

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues here. Let's talk about the first (the title).

"How to check what I'm going to commit?"

You can use `git status` to view which files ...

- You haven't added yet (with `git add <file>`). These are "untracked files".
- You haven't committed yet. These are the "changes to be committed" that *will* be committed when you run `git commit`.

This example illustrates the difference.

```
<O.o> git status
On branch example-branch
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    exampleFile.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
<O.o> git add exampleFile.txt 
<O.o> git status
On branch example-branch
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   exampleFile.txt

<O.o> git commit -m "touched exampleFile.txt"
[example-branch 8a2b990432] touched exampleFile.txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 exampleFile.txt
<O.o> git status
On branch example-branch
nothing to commit, working tree clean
<O.o>
```

Now let's talk about the second (the last question).

"How can I check which local commits I need to push?"

For *that* you'll want to use `git diff origin/master HEAD`. If you have no changes staged for commit, you can safely leave off the `HEAD` part. If you want just a list of files and not the code diff, tack on the

`--name-only` 
option.

See also this thread:
[How can I see what I am about to push with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636914/how-can-i-see-what-i-am-about-to-push-with-git)