# Why git is showing other persons commit to in my git status?

Tags: git, github

Further to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655869/how-to-check-what-im-gonna-commit), I'm seeing following output :

```
commit 859370e0faec6d708466512eb000140d974292f6
Author: John B <johnb@company.in>
Date:   Wed Mar 26 11:55:38 2014 +0530

    Fixed Bug #61852(FeedBack)
```

Here I'm seeing changes of the some other developer(John B). What should I do now? should I commit `local commits` to `develop` branch, OR should I inform that developer about it?

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I this is what I was expecting. Thank you. I'll move on. I'll accept the answer if you could paste it as answer. Thank you very much again

Comment: btw. if those commits from the other developer are on your branch, you will probably need to `pull` again anyways. But git will merge it automatically (or generate a conflict that you must solve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He changed the code. He did commit. He pushed it. Then you pulled it. And now you see his commit in the log. Why would you want to inform him that he did a change that you see? It's 100% normal. Move on.

If you are worried because you were in the middle of some changes, and in the meantime he changed something - OK. It's normal too. But he was faster. It is now up to you to review and merge/rebase/commit such code that will be safe and valid not only with your 'starting point' but also with his changes. That's the basic assumption of 'merge' that must happen at some point of time between branches (or even the same branch when different people work on it).

The most important thing is that if you were working on different files/lines, then GIT will probably merge them automatically. It may go silently. Still, it's your business logic, so you should review, just for the small probability of him doing something that breaks your current unpublished code.