# Git: How can I find out why `git commit` and `git push` do not commit or push any files?

Tags: git, github

Suddenly git push stopped working from one day on my Ubuntu 14 machine.

I tried with different projects but the issue is still there.
No error message is also being displayed, it keeps showing a blink.

I know it's a weird thing. How can I fix this?

```
git push origin my_branch_name
```

Comment: It usually shows blink when there is nothing to push.

Comment: It also shows the blink when you need to enter git login and password.
I have some files which need to be pushed.

Comment: Ok. Were your credentials cached, and now it ask you again to enter them?

Comment: Have you actually committed the files you need to push? Try doing `git status` to check. Sometimes it's the obvious things...

Comment: @VonC No my credentials were not cached. I used to enter every time, I make a push. I am waiting git to ask me to enter my credentials but its not.

Comment: @Lydia Ralph,  No my git status is clean. I already added and committed as well.

$> git status
 nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Try this to check if you actually have any files to push: `git diff --stat --cached [remote/branch]`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636914/how-can-i-see-what-i-am-about-to-push-with-git

Comment: Lydia Ralph, I tried this command
  $> git diff --stat --cached reseller-admin-panel

It shows nothing.

Comment: Also, use SSH keys. No more entering passwords...

Comment: @ThankyouAll. It worked now  some wild guess!

Comment: I don't think it works all the time but the answer is I took the pull from the same branch(which failed) with error message then pushed it. It worked. I know its kinda wired.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out, since it is wired thing, it worked with some wild guess.

I first took the pull from the same branch which am trying to push. And then I tried pushing to the same branch it worked.

```
 git pull origin my_branch_name
  # got some error message, then
 git push origin my_branch_name.
```

Thats how it worked.