# git tags not pushed to remote yet

Tags: git

In Git, I created some local tags, and only some of them I wanted to push to origin.

After a while, I want to check what tags were missed from pushing to remote.

do we have command to show all tags which are in the local repo but not pushed to remote repo yet?

Thank you.

Comment: `git ls-remote --tags origin` will show all tags in the remote repository. In combination with `git tags` and a textual difference, this should give the answer. Not sure if there's a builtin way.

Answer (score 18):

Considering a [`git push` can also push tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745250/6309), you could use the git push `--dry-run` to preview a push and see if tags are pushed or not.

```
git push --tags --dry-run
```

That would list the local tags which are not present on the remote.
If the output is empty, all tags are already pushed.

Note that, as mentioned in "[How can I see what I am about to push with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3636939/6309)":

> The problem with [`git push --dry-run`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) is that it still requires write permission at the remote.
>   So if you have a clone without permission to push upstream, but you'd like to see what your local unpushed changes are, `--dry-run` won't do it.

In that case, the scripting solution mentioned by [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611831/git-tags-not-pushed-to-remote-yet/30612263#comment49290772_30611831) (`git ls-remote --tags origin` vs. `git tag`) is another option.