# How can I see what git commits will be pushed for a NEW git branch?

Tags: git

Similar question to [How can I see what I am about to push with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636914/how-can-i-see-what-i-am-about-to-push-with-git) - I want to see the descriptions (commit messages) of commits that will be pushed, but for a new local branch. Normally `git cherry -v` (**Alex Nolasko**'s answer) shows exactly what I want, but this fails for a branch that doesn't yet exist in the remote.

To be more precise, I'd like to see all commits that are not yet in the remote. For example, if I started out on branch "master", made commit 1, then created branch "feature_a" from master and made commit 2 then (still without pushing) created branch "feature_b" from feature_a and made commit 3 I'd like to see commits 1, 2, and 3 listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try (for a new branch not yet pushed):

```
git log origin/$(git merge-base master mybranch)..feature_b
```

The [OP EM0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536933/em0) used `HEAD` for the current branch:

```
git log $(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)..HEAD
```

That would list all commits accessible from `feature_b` but not where `feature_b` starts (from `master`, as seem by [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base))
That would include commits 2 and 3 (assuming commit 1 from `master` was pushed, or else the remote repo would be completely empty)

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using a slightly modified version of this: I moved the "origin/" into the merge-base command and used HEAD instead of hardcoding the branch, i.e. `git log $(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)..HEAD`

Comment: @EM0 Thank you. I have included your version in the answer for more visibility.