# Netbeans: How to show all (git) commits that will be pushed?

Tags: git, netbeans, push, commit

How to show all (git) commits than will be pushed within Netbeans ? Netbeans 7.3 simply pushes everything without showing a list of all commits first (like IntelliJ IDEA does).

Answer (score 4):

The current [NetBeans Git plugin dialog for push](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#push) doesn't support any preview option.

What is missing a simple `log` feature, as shown in "[Preview a git push](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2176278/6309)":

```
git log origin/master..master
```

But depending on your [push policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309), and remote refspec, it can be more complex (you can push several branches instead of one).
You need (as with [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176524/6309)) to interpret the result of:

```
git push --dry-run --porcelain
```

NetBeans Git plugin doesn't implement that, which leaves you only with a **command-line workaround**.

Answer (score 4):

In NetBeans 8 you can see your local commits by right-clicking on the project Git->Remote->Show Outgoing;

i.e.

Show In/Outgoing is displaying unpulled (unpushed) commits into (from) a specific branch.

Comment: Interesting. More accurate than my 4 years old answer. +1