# How to compare GIT Remote Repo and local in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, version-control, github

I use git in Netbeans 7.3. I have classes committed to local repository. I want to compare the changes between local and remote repository which is Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in "[Netbeans: How to show all (git) commits than will be pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17941008/6309)", there is no support for and advanced `git log` (or `git diff` viewer) [in Git for Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html).

So the shell remains the backup option, with commands like the ones mentioned in "[compare local git branch with remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1800783/6309)":

```
git diff --stat --color master..origin/master
git diff master..origin/master
```