# Show all commits in a git branch since original branching point from master

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

I'm looking for a way to view all commits on active branch since branching point (and including it) and hopefully since branching from master.

For example situation like:

```
A-B-C-D (master)
   \
    E-F (branch A)
```

I want to get commits F, E and B while F is the HEAD.

And for

```
A-B-C-D   (master)
   \
    E-F   (branch B)
       \
        G (branch C)
```

I want to get commits G, F, E, B in case G is current HEAD. Displaying this information with --graph option would be also great.

For now I have come up with

```
git log master^..HEAD
```

But it seems to be displaying too much information (like commits from other branches).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: isn't your answer over there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725531/show-commits-since-branch-creation

Comment: @FredericClose that question doesn't cover the second case.

Comment: Could you post your output of `git log master..HEAD`? Commits from other branches may be showing up because they are also in HEAD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From "[How Do I run Git Log to see changes only for a specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649356/how-do-i-run-git-log-to-see-changes-only-for-a-specific-branch)", this should be enough:

```
git log  --boundary master..
# or
git log  --boundary --no-merges master..
```

More concise representation:

```
git log --boundary --no-merges --pretty='%C(yellow)%h%d %Creset%an %Cgreen%ar:%Creset %s' --graph master..
```

(add `--boundary`, as [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015808/show-all-commits-in-a-git-branch-since-original-branching-point-from-master/20016493#comment29818159_20016493), in order to include what '`B`' commit which would otherwise be excluded from the git log result)