# How to determine git commits on a branch but not inherited from different branch?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, git-log

I am trying to determine git commits on a particular branch, which excludes git commits inherited.

Comment: can you share the details exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate [show commits since branch creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725531/show-commits-since-branch-creation)

Comment: The question addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569/how-to-get-the-changes-on-a-branch-in-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the changes on a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569/how-to-get-the-changes-on-a-branch-in-git)