# how to view changed files on git branch and difference

Tags: git

I was trying to do this which didn't show anything different
[How to get the changes on a branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569/how-to-get-the-changes-on-a-branch-in-git)

I did a branch from master and since then changes have been made on master and my branch (called performance).  All I want is

1. The list of files changed/touched since branching "performance" branch (all files were committed)
2. Show the complete difference of all those files changed/touched.

When doing git diff origin/master, it lists all changes on both branches :(.

What is the command since git diff HEAD..performance shows nothing(and ... also shows nothing)?  Also, using log in the same way with .. and with ... also shows nothing.

If I do git log, I do see the commit I made on the performance branch with my comment about performance as well.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Can you try this and see if its what you are after? git diff hash1 hash2

Comment: I don't know which hashes to use as I only know the last commit was on this branch but I am not sure about the other commits and where it finally forked from master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the branch point.  You can do this with the `merge-base` command:

```
$ git merge-base performance master
cafebabe01234567...
```

Note: If you don't remember the `merge-base` command, you can always use `gitx`/`gitk`/`gitg`/etc. to find the branch point visually.

Then, you can do a diff from the branch point to the tip of the performance branch:

```
$ git diff cafebabe01234567... performance
```

Or, in a single line,

```
$ git diff $(git merge-base performance master) performance
```

Remember that `git diff` takes options, if you want to change how it displays the differences.  See the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).

Comment: Cheers, I'll know the next time!

Comment: well, it is definitely giving the wrong fork revision as the date on that is way way back in May and I just created this branch yesterday sometime.  Why would it give me something from May on what is a very new branch?

Comment: oh, and I took the hash from git merge-base performance master and then did a git log and searched for the hash and it is way back in May which is definitely wrong.

Comment: oh crap. this really screwed things up.  I ran that command on performance branch which gave me that hash but then when I did git checkout master to get back on master, it says I am behind by 238 commits...it wasn't doing this a few hours ago when I was on master branch and switching back and forth....how do I fix this?  I thought the command you gave me was not modifying anything but it seems to have done some stuff that I didn't want to do to my repository.  My performance branch is local as well so I can't just blow away and clone :( :(

Comment: ah crap, did a git pull, go back to performance branch and run same merge-base command and now it gives a different hash...this just screws things up worse

Comment: I am not sure what happened but now it seems to have stabilized and is actually giving me a commit that was probably the fork....this is soooo weird.

Comment: Neither `git merge-base` nor `git diff` will modify your repository, and neither command requires that you check out a branch.  They will produce the same results no matter which branch you are on when you run the commands.

Comment: However, you will get a different result if you start modifying your repository with `git pull`, which is equivalent to running `git fetch` and `git merge` (both of which modify the repository).