# How to view the changes of a Git branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-diff

I have feature/bug-fix branch (say `topic`) with a bunch of commits and want to present them to my colleagues before merging them into `master`. I can manually find the common ancestor of my branch and the master branch and compare that to its tip:

```
$ git diff d0a2eaf..03a025f
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to view changed files on git branch and difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493925/how-to-view-changed-files-on-git-branch-and-difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate finding the common ancestor using [`git merge-base`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html) and that to the tip of your branch:

```
$ git diff `git merge-base master topic` topic
```

Or simply use [`git diff`'s dot-notation for "Comparing branches"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) to view changes that occurred on the `topic` branch since when it was started of the `master` branch:

```
$ git diff master...topic
```

Comment: Note that `git diff` effectively special-cases the three-dot syntax, `master...my-branch`, to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

if you current branch is your feature branch, doing a `git diff master` will do a diff between your current HEAD and the named branch (which is essentially exactly what you're mentioning).

Comment: This requires interactive context switching (`git checkout topic`), which may not be possible with an unclean working copy. It would be more elegant to get the diff without depending on the working copy.