# git log in branch without merge to master

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am using the following command to find files that were committed into branch:

```
git log --name-status --oneline master..branch_name
```

But I want to exclude master commits, so only commits to specific branch. Like Bitbucket diff. Do you know how to get only branch changed/added files?

Comment: How about just plain `git log`?

Comment: But it's a plain git log, only with filters.

Comment: I had something else in mind, which was wrong anyway.  Have a look here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569/how-to-get-the-changes-on-a-branch-in-git

Answer (score 1):

```
git log --name-status --no-merges origin/master..branch_name
```

Comment: Why `origin/master`?  I upvoted for the `--no-merges`, but I don't understand the remote-tracking branch part.

Comment: It's compare not with local master branch, but with origin.